# extending subprocess.Popen through inheritence

Tags: python, inheritance, subprocess

As a system administrator I find myself many times writing scripts that call command via subprocess. Sometimes, I don't want the commands to actually execute, and I want just to see what would be executed. Hence, my codes were full in lines like this:

```
alaroffcmd = 'someBinary -h %s' %someHostName
...
if options.tstmd:       
   print alaroffcmd
else:
   chctxt = sp.Popen(alamoffcmd,shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE) 
   ...
```

I was thinking that a 'testmode' would be very usefull.

As an example of usage:

```
lsp=nPopen('ls -l',shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, testmode=True)
```

Will just print the command to be issued. This seems redundant maybe, but in real life, I sometimes call subprocess with some very complex command, which are decided based on conditions that are determined in the script (above there is an example with `someHostName`)

I used this as [an example how to extend a function by overriding it's **init** method,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/492620). Here is how I extended `subprocess.Popen`, to fit my needs:

```
import subprocess as sp

class nPopen(sp.Popen):
    def __init__(self, args, bufsize=0, executable=None,
                 stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
                 preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False,
                 cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False,
                 startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,testmode=False):

        if testmode: 
            print args
            return None

     p = sp.Popen.__init__(self,args, bufsize, executable,
                 stdin, stdout, stderr,
                 preexec_fn, close_fds, shell,
                 cwd, env, universal_newlines,
                 startupinfo, creationflags)

        return p
```

This works as I expect it, but since I have never extended a class by overriding its `__init__` method, I was wondering about the correctness of this, or in other words:
Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?
Should I use `super` for better Python3 compatibility ?

Comment: BTW, `__init__()` functions don't return anything.

Comment: @martineau, as a convention ? or as a fact?

Comment: A fact. Actually all functions return something, `None` by default if they don't explicitly return something else, but whatever it is, it's ignored in the case of a class's `__init__()` function. You know, you could just change the value of `Popen` in the module after you `import subrocess as sp` to be your own function. i.e. `sp.Popen = my_function`.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for making that clear. It works also without the statement `return p` in the end. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Yes, all an `__init__()` usually does is initialize the already created instance's attributes (and possibly other miscellaneous things). Class instances are normally created by the class's `__new__` function inherited from `object` in modern Python, and as such isn't commonly overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use a subclass at all, since it sounds like you don't want to change the functionality of the `Popen` object.  It sounds like you just want to change the functionality of its constructor.

I would create a dummy `Popen` class that just prints out its arguments.  (This is written using Python 3.x style, but it's easy enough to translate to Python 2.x.)

```
class DummyPopen(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        print('Popen({})'.format(
            ', '.join([repr(arg) for arg in args] +
                      ['{}={!r}'.format(*pair) for pair in kw.items()])))
        self.returncode = 1

    def wait(self):
        return 1

    # et cetera
```

You can then trigger use of the dummy class however you want.

```
def Popen(*args, testmode=False, **kw):
    if testmode:
        return DummyPopen(*args, **kw)
    return subprocess.Popen(*args, **kw)
```

Or even:

```
if testmode:
    Popen = DummyPopen
else:
    Popen = subprocess.Popen
```

This takes advantage of the "duck typing" conventions of Python -- any object which has the same interface as a `Popen` object is functionally indistinguishable from a `Popen` object, as long as you don't abuse `isinstance()` too much.

Note that *both* of these methods allow you to import `Popen` from the module.

```
from mymodule import Popen
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me such a nice way not to abuse inheritance. Your second way with `def Popen` is more clear to me (I am not really into Python3, yet..) . It has the advantage I can also import it from other scripts, compared to the last option ...

Comment: @Oz123: The last option can also be imported from other scripts.

Comment: How can you import a collection of statements not grouped in a function or a class?

Comment: @Oz123: Classes and functions are not special, they are just global variables and you can import any global variable from a module.  For example, if you write `x = 5` in module `mymodule`, then you can refer to it as `mymodule.x`.

Comment: I failed to ask the wrong quesiton. When you said you can import the 3rd option, i thought you mean the `if testmode:
    Popen = DummyPopen
else:
    Popen = subprocess.Popen` structure ... I know you can import a variable or a function ...

Comment: @Oz123: Yes, you can import `Popen` from the `if testmode: ...` statement.  If you failed to ask the wrong question, what is the right question?  What are you trying to do with the last option?

Comment: one more thing, I think I understand your comment. When I import the module, that hold the new Popen, the statement `testmode` is evaluated, so it decides which Popen to import? the only problem with this is that `testmode` from the importing module is not available inside where Popen is defined... after giving some thought, and correcting my typos, here is the solution I came up with: http://paste.debian.net/209684/ this is quite a journey ... thanks for making me scratch my brain.

Comment: Hmmm... let me phrase it this way.  When you import a module, all of the statements at the top level of that module get evaluated (but only once, even if you import multiple times).  `Popen` is just a global variable in a module.  It doesn't matter if `Popen` is created using a `class` statement, or a `def` statement, or something else.  When you import something, all you are doing is accessing the global variables in another module.  Hope this helps.